# performFiltering: List<>

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I just want to perform a filter search from List but I only have ArrayList source code. How to convert it when using List instead of ArrayList?

Below is my code:

```
 @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        //CHECK CONSTRAINT VALIDITY
         if(constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0)
         {
             //CHANGE TO UPPER
             constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
             //STORE OUR FILTERED ORDER
             ArrayList<OrderModel> filteredOrder = new ArrayList<>();

             for (int i=0; i<filteredOrder.size(); i++) {
                 // CHECK
                 if (filterList.get(i).getCustomerName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) {
                     //ADD CUSTOMER TO FILTERED ORDERS
                    filteredOrder.add(filterList.get(i));
                    Log.d("Testing.....","You are here --->" + filteredOrder);
                 }
             }
             results.count = filteredOrder.size();
             results.values = filteredOrder;
         } else {
             results.count = filterList.size();
             results.values = filterList;
         }
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try replacing `ArrayList<OrderModel>` with `List<OrderModel>`?

Comment: it doesn't matter if you are using a `List` or `ArrayList`

Comment: What is `filterList`? What problem are you really facing?

Comment: just replace `Arraylists` by `list` just take any one of them..else you would get type mismatch..

Comment: Yes, I did. It requests me to implement override method and I don't know where I should place codes from below here              ArrayList<OrderModel> filteredOrder = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: public CustomFilter(List<OrderModel> filterList, OrdersAdapter ordersAdapter) {
        this.filterList = filterList;
        this.ordersAdapter = ordersAdapter;
    }

Comment: No result/s appears when I typed on the search bar.

Comment: Are you sure, you replaced `ArrayList` with `java.util.List` and not `java.awt.List` ?

Comment: I don't understand what is your exact problem. ArrayList is an implementation of the interface List that Java already provides to you, you got nothing to implement there. Besides, filteredOrder got no elements after the instantiation, your loop is never executed because its size is 0, and 0 is not greater than 0.

Comment: Yes. I'm sure. I include import java.util.List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be fine if you replace

```
ArrayList<OrderModel> filteredOrder = new ArrayList<>();
```

with

```
List<OrderModel> filteredOrder = new ArrayList<>();
```

but be carefull, in imports you have to have

```
import java.util.List;
```

while you used only `add()` and `size()` it has to work.

Answer (score 0):

As RubioRic said that my loop is never executed because its size is 0, and 0 is not greater than 0. He is right. I don't notice that problem. Thumb up! In addition, I have replaced also the one line to this:

```
List<OrderModel> filteredOrder = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we are moving towards java 10, try Stream api -

```
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc","xyz","acd");
        List<String> filteredList = list.stream().filter((element) ->
        {
           return element.startsWith("a");
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(filteredList);
```

You can insert your own predicate here.